# Android Webview CPU usage

Tags: java, android, performance

I am using Webview in an Android application. This application receives an event for each 250 ms and updates the DOM element. For this simple operation the CPU usage goes to 14 to 16%. For the same operation the native app is consuming only 4 to 5%. Why is Webview consuming so much of CPU for updating one DOM element. Is there a way we can optimize this in Android?

Comment: Out of interest, what are you updating 4 times a second?

Comment: This is a healthcare application that monitors heartbeat and we need to update this frequently. The native application is fine with that.. but we are prototyping to make it HTML5 application and facing this limitation. In our experiments we narrowed down the bottleneck is due to DOM update.

Answer (score 1):

I've also faced with such problem.
As I've understood, that something is going wrong with the timers in WebView. I've tried to start/stop the timers (this is available only for all WebViews in application) with:

```
(new WebView(activity)).pauseTimers();
```

and

```
(new WebView(activity)).resumeTimers();
```

and the CPU usage & the power consumption has been essentially decreased.